# is it possible to create global UDF on snowflake data warehouse

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create a function once and have it be available everywhere on the account.

I don't want to have to specify fully-qualified name in all usages.

And I don't want to create it in every database, and possibly on every schema.

Ideally, it is accessible across the account without specifying database / schema.

For example, suppose I want a case-insensitive contains function available everywhere.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION udf_icontains(val varchar, search_pattern varchar)
    RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS
$$
    contains(lower(val), lower(search_pattern))
$$;
```

It seems I must create it on every database and every schema in order to reference without FQN.

Answer (score 2):

You can create it in a single database and schema, grant public access, and then reference it in queries using its fully-qualified name (db.schema.udf...) from everywhere.

Comment: i know i can reference fqn but i am just wishing could be created essentially in a global, or account-level namespace.  like how system functions are global.

Comment: Just create a public database with a name like `global` or `account` (we call ours `utils`) with a public schema called `udfs`. You already have a `udf_` prefix in the name of your UDF, so `global.udfs.icontains()` is not that much longer to type.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a public database with a name like `global` or `account` (we call ours `utils`) with a public schema called `udfs`.

You already have a `udf_` prefix in the name of your UDF; `global.udfs.icontains` is not much longer to type than `udf_icontains`.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS global;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS global.udfs
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE global TO ROLE public;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA global.udfs TO ROLE public;
GRANT USAGE ON FUTURE FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA global.udfs TO ROLE public;
GRANT USAGE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA global.udfs TO ROLE public;
```